# Overlay div fill entire parent div including when scrolled

Tags: html, css

I have an overlay which should fill an entire div.

HTML:

```
<div class="phone">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .phone {
      position: relative;
      width: 300px;
      height: 500px;
      padding: 15px;
      background: #F2F4F5;
      overflow: hidden;
      cursor: default;
    }

    .overlay {
      display: none;
      background: rgba(27, 35, 41, 0.5);
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      z-index: 1;
    }
```

I have some JS adding content to the `.phone` div and when content is added, it automatically scrolls to the bottom of the `.phone` div. However, the overlay only stretches to fit the 300x500 original size. So when it scrolls down the overlay no longer covers the entire div.

If I add `position: fixed` to the overlay, it fills the whole screen instead of the `.phone` div only.

Comment: Everything seems to be working? Can you include your js? https://jsfiddle.net/eewp92my/1/

Comment: add content inside the `.phone` div? If so, your code works fine in FF46.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Place the overlay outside of the .phone div so that it is a child of the body element. Then set the Body to position relative.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="phone"></div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    position:relative;
}
.overlay {
      display: none;
      background: rgba(27, 35, 41, 0.5);
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      z-index: 1;
}

.phone {
      width: 300px;
      height: 500px;
      padding: 15px;
      background: #F2F4F5;
      overflow: hidden;
      cursor: default;
    }
```

Comment: body position:relative; fixed my issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you give him position fixed he will be :

```
 top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
```

To the body and not your div if you want him to take the full size of his parent you give him

```
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
```

```css
.phone {
      position: relative;
      width: 300px;
      height: 500px;
      padding: 15px;
      background: red;
      overflow: hidden;
      cursor: default;
    }

    .overlay {
     /* display: none;*/
      background: pink;
      position: absolute;
      /*top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;*/
      height:100%;
      width:100%;
      z-index: 1;
    }
```

```html
<div class="phone">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh, thats why this method never worked for me. I forgot to set the overlay to fixed, so when I would scroll the overlay would not adjust and would just scroll off the page. Was not my question - but you solved an issue I could not figure out in the past. Thanks!